# Explain why the integral test can't be used to determine whether the series is convergent

Tags: calculus

I have a homework question on the integral test chapter of my book and I'm not sure i'm answering this correctly.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \frac{\cos \pi n}{\sqrt n } $$
Now I know that in order for me to apply the integral test I have to have a decreasing, continuous, positive function.
So my answer to this question is **I cant apply the integral test because this function is not a decreasing positive function on the interval $[1,\infty)$.** Is this an accurate statement?
I guess I can actually ask this question in a more precise manner and that is.
How can i look at a function and tell if its decreasing and positive? I seem to have a conceptual block on this one.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: As explained by vadim123, one cannot apply the integral test. However, one can get *something* out of the integral test. The absolute value of the $n$-th term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. By the integral test, $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ does not converge. So although by the alternating series test the original series converges, by the integral test it does not converge absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternating series, you probably want the alternating series test, not the integral test.

The integral test is for positive series, while this one alternates $+,-$.  For that reason alone you can't use the integral test.

Comment: I havent learned that yet. this is a homework problem in my integral test chapter. I have to explain why I cant apply integral test here.

Comment: vadim thank you it makes sense. could you comment on the second half of my question. Do you have any tip on how to look at series and see if its a decreasing positive series? I conceptually have a problem seeing that.